# iTextSharp - Scaling and positioning page

Tags: itext

I am reading an existing PDF file into a new PDF file, and scaling the first page based on the page dimensions. The page gets scaled to 90-95% in order to make room for some footer text.  The problem I have is that the resulting scaled page leaves white space at the top of the page, NOT the bottom.  Is there a way to control the results so that they start in the top left of the page and not the bottom left?

Here's my code that adds the scaled page:
    `cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, scaleSize, 0, 0, scaleSize, 5, 20);`

Object "cb" is a PDFContentByte class, while "scaleSize" is a float set to .9 or .95.  The scaling works great, but the positioning is an issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out: the value of "20" for the final parameter was incorrect.  A value of 100 is far more suitable for my purposes, and now I understand far better the coordinate system in PDF/iText.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out: the value of "20" for the final parameter was incorrect. A value of 100 is far more suitable for my purposes, and now I understand far better the coordinate system in PDF/iText.  For those interested, the 0, 0 point for a PDF document is the lower left corner.

Comment: Note that the 0,0 point is *usually* the lower-left corner of the page. The dimensions of a page are defined by the `MediaBox` and the `CropBox` using a rectangle, such as `[ x1 y1 x2 y2 ]`. The coordinate defined by `x1` and `y1` defines the lower-left corner. In most cases, `x1` and `y1` are 0.